# no match for operator =, constructor creates a pointer

Tags: c++

For an assignment I had to create a LinkedList class, here is the header info:

```
struct element{
    Event *data;
    element *next;
};


class LinkedList {
    public:
        element *first, *last;
        LinkedList();
```

The constructor is :

```
LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
}
```

And I'm trying to make a queue with it like this:

```
class EventQueue {
public:
    LinkedList events;
```

And finally the error occurs here where I try to create the constructor for
EventQueue by doing:

```
EventQueue::EventQueue(){
    events = new LinkedList();
}
```

And it throws an error, no match for operator =, operand types are LinkedList and LinkedList*.

Why does the constructor for LinkedList create a pointer? I can't find what would cause that or how to fix it.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses everyone I feel like a huge idiot, I was getting a bunch of undefined reference errors and thought I had to change the constructor, so I tried the whole new object thing. In actuality, the error was in my makefile where I didn't properly link the LinkedList.o file. Thanks everyone for answering my question!

Comment: The constructor doesn't create a pointer. `new` does. This should be explained in any introductory C++ book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is used for dynamic allocation of objects, so it always returns a pointer.

Since you've declared `events` as a `LinkedList`, not `LinkedList*`, you don't need to do anything to initialize it. The constructor for `LinkedList` will be called automatically when you create an `EventQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `new LinkedList()` returns a pointer to a new `LinkedList` object, whereas your data member `LinkedList events;` is an object (and not a pointer to an object).
Note that with `LinkedList events;` object `events` automatically gets (default)-initialized when an `EventQueue` object is created; at this point, the default constructor of `LinkedList` gets called implicitly. 
So simply remove the line `events = new LinkedList();`